# I keep getting error when trying to send transaction signed by web3.eth.sign with web3.eth.sendsignedtransaction

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ethsign

**I get an error**

`Error: TypedTransaction with ID 40 unknown at t.TransactionFactory.fromSerializedData`

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
const txData = { nonce: "0x" + parseInt(nonce, 10).toString(16), from: address, to: to, gasLimit: "0x" + parseInt(gasAmount, 10).toString(16), gasPrice: "0x" + parseInt(fee, 10).toString(16), value: "0x" + parseInt(balance, 10).toString(16), };

console.log(txData)

let hexObject = new ethereumjs.Tx(txData);
let hexString = '0x' + hexObject.serialize().toString('hex'),
    encoded = {
        encoding: 'hex'
    }
const rawHash = web3.utils.sha3(hexString, encoded);

console.log('rawHash: ' + rawHash)

let txHash = await web3.eth.sign(rawHash, address);
console.log('txHash: ' + txHash)

const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(txHash, function (error, hash) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  else {
    console.log(hash)
  }
})
```